# Facebook messenger bot reaction notification

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger-bot

I have created my messenger bot and I am sending optedin user messages.

However I would like also to handle their reactions to my messages.

My callback url is working ok, for messages sent by them, for read events etc, but no reaction information.

Does anybody know if this is possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today there is a webhook to handle reactions

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events/message-reactions/

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no webhook event sent for reactions, and no way to detect them.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I hope they publish it later, as it is very strange that you can listen for a message containing the word like but not for a like reaction!